# What's the correct way of updating a foreign key in an entity framework object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I'm using `EF code-first` and I have a question...

I have 2 objects: `Product` and `Category`. In the `Product` object I have a `CategoryId` property and also a `Category` property.

My question is, if I want to update a category in the product object, which property should I change? The `CategoryId` or the `Category`?

I'm updating both at the moment, but it seems a bit weird to me...

thanks!

Comment: var product = GetProductById(1);
    var category = GetCategoryById(10);

    product.CategoryId = category.CategoryId;
    product.Category = category;

    //save chages...

Comment: Change one property that is easier in your context

Comment: You can even remove the `CategoryId` property. EF can do without and still create a foreign key.

Comment: really? cool! You should add this comment as an answer...

Comment: [Beware of the differences though](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/05/foreign-key-vs-independent-associations-in-ef-4/) (See at the bottom of the article). I prefer independent associations, where storage implementations don't bleed into the class model, but foreign key association can be easier to handle (just set an integer value, for instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is just:

```
var product = GetProductById(1);
product.CategoryId = 10;
// Save changes
```

That's all, you don't need to load nor set the navigation property. This simple code is one of the reasons why foreign key properties (like `CategoryId`) are useful.